# Convert a row data to columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, multiple-columns, rows

I have a scenario in which I have three columns with multiple rows, I need to select them in single row.
Below I am attaching temporary table scenario.

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
  PersonID INT ,
  PhoneType VARCHAR(20) ,
  PhoneNumber VARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT  INTO #Temp
    ( PersonID ,
      PhoneType ,
      PhoneNumber 
    )
    SELECT  1212 ,
            'Business' ,
            '123456789'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  1212 ,
            'Cell' ,
            '741852963'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  1212 ,
            'Other' ,
            '987654321'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  1212 ,
            'Home' ,
            '951357852'

SELECT  *
FROM    #Temp

DROP TABLE #Temp
```

I need to Display,

```
PersonID|Business|123456789|Cell|741852963|Other|987654321|Home|951357852
```

Can anybody help?

I have to combine this result with another Select Query,How may I do?

Comment: You need to Use `PIVOT`

Comment: Is the `PhoneType` always these 4?

Comment: @FelixPamittan now it can be any with random order, not every person should have four phone , but at least one must

Comment: you might need to consider the data quality before transforming it: what happens if there are 5 or even more rows for a single "person"? might there be more than one "home" or "cell" for example. if a person changes address what happens to these phone records?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/55f15/3/0)

```
SELECT
    PersonID,
    Business    = MAX(CASE WHEN PhoneType = 'Business' THEN PhoneNumber END),
    Cell        = MAX(CASE WHEN PhoneType = 'Cell' THEN PhoneNumber END),
    Other       = MAX(CASE WHEN PhoneType = 'Other' THEN PhoneNumber END),
    Home        = MAX(CASE WHEN PhoneType = 'Home' THEN PhoneNumber END)
FROM #Temp
GROUP BY PersonID
```

---

If you have unknown number of `PhoneType`s, do a dynamic crosstab:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/55f15/1/0)

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
SELECT @sql = 
'SELECT
    PersonID' + CHAR(10)

SELECT @sql = @sql +
'   , MAX(CASE WHEN PhoneType = ''' + PhoneType + ''' THEN PhoneNumber END) AS' + QUOTENAME(PhoneType) + CHAR(10)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT PhoneType FROM #Temp) t

SELECT @sql = @sql +
'FROM #Temp
GROUP BY PersonID'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: This way to concatenate strings is not usable in ad-hoc queries (such as inline UDF). Concatenation is better be done with FOR XML PATH...

Answer (score 4):

You can use this code. It may be Help you.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(PhoneType) 
                    from #Temp
                    group by PhoneType, PersonID
                    order by PersonID
             FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')

SET @query = N'SELECT ' + @cols + N' from 
             (
                select *
                from #Temp
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(PhoneNumber)
                for PhoneType in (' + @cols + N')
            ) p'

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @QUERY;
```

Comment: You do not need any dynamic SQL here... Better avoid dynamic SQL if not  really needed...

Answer (score 4):

You can use PIVOT like below,

```
SELECT  *
FROM    #Temp
PIVOT(MAX(PhoneNumber) 
          FOR PhoneType IN ([Business],[Cell],[Other],[Home])) AS PVTTable
```

OR I think you want something like below,

```
SELECT PersonID = STUFF((SELECT  PhoneType + ' | ' + PhoneNumber + ' | '
    FROM #Temp 
     ORDER BY PersonID
     FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 0, '')
FROM #Temp AS x
GROUP BY PersonID, PhoneType
ORDER BY PersonID;
```

Last one,

```
DECLARE @MainColumn AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
SET @MainColumn = (SELECT  PersonID =  STUFF((SELECT PhoneType + ' | ' + PhoneNumber + ' | '
    FROM #Temp 
     ORDER BY PersonID
     FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 0, '')
FROM #Temp AS x
GROUP BY PersonID)

SELECT 'PersonID | ' + @MainColumn  AS FinalResult
```

Comment: rep for using "FOR XML" method.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(MAX) --To store the result
--Make the result by appending each rows
SELECT  @String = ISNULL(@String,'PersonID')  + ' | '+ PhoneType + ' | ' + PhoneNumber
FROM    #Temp
--return the string
SELECT @String
```

Comment: output shows like, `1212 | Business | 123456789 | Cell | 741852963 | Other | 987654321 | Home | 951357852` - BTW nice option!

Comment: This way to concatenate strings is not usable in ad-hoc queries (such as inline UDF). Concatenation is better be done with `FOR XML PATH` (and also better performance)

Answer (score 2):

My solution would be:

```
SELECT outerTbl.MyDisplayValue
FROM
(
    SELECT  DISTINCT CAST(PersonID AS varchar(MAX)) + Concatenated.Contacts
    FROM #Temp AS tbl
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT '|' + innerTbl.PhoneType + '|' + innerTbl.PhoneNumber
        FROM #Temp AS innerTbl  
        WHERE innerTbl.PersonID=tbl.PersonID
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ) AS Concatenated(Contacts)
    FOR XML PATH('')
) AS outerTbl(MyDisplayValue)
```

Comment: output would be, `1212|Business|123456789|Cell|741852963|Other|987654321|Home|951357852` -

Comment: @curiousguy, yes, I assumed that the OP does not want the word "PersonID" in the first place but the actual Person's ID connected to these contacts. Anyway this is a rather strange construction :-)

Comment: yes it should be actual Person's ID not the "PersonID" -

Comment: @curiousguy, may I ask why you posted the output? Is there something wrong with it I don't see?

Comment: @Shungo - actually it is for DareDevil - so that we can come to know what is the expected output! nothing else. I'll remove that comment.

Comment: @curiousguy, Thank you for the help :-)

Comment: @DareDevil, you might want to place your "thank you" to a better place. This comment below my answer will not reach the others. And you might vote up all helpful answers and check the best (your free choice!) as accepted? This would be even better :-)

Comment: Above mentioned OP was just a reference only, I wanted to select separate columns `|` was the line reference